# Input field in a table element: can I assign it to a class?

Tags: javascript, css

I am new to javascript (although otherwise old, if not wise).  Ondřej Žára wrote a nifty vanilla js spreadsheet (https://jsfiddle.net/user/ondras/fiddles/) that is an excellent starting point for my own project, so I'm trying to work off that.  Here is how he sets up the sheet:

```
for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
    var row = document.querySelector("table").insertRow(-1);
    for (var j=0; j<6; j++) {
        var letter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0)+j-1);
        row.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = i&&j ? "<input id='"+ letter+i +"'/>" : i||letter;
    }
}
```

He then uses CSS as follows to highlight the cells.  It is all stuff I want.

```
input {
    border: none;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 2px;
}

input:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}

input:focus {
    background-color: #ccf;
}

input:not(:focus) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Finally, here is my problem:  the cells are all inputs, and controlled by the CSS keyword "input".  But I want to add other inputs (buttons, fields, etc.) and all my new inputs are covered by the same input styling.  I think the cleanest thing to do would be to make the cell inputs into their own class, but so far I have not figured out how...

(OK.  I found one workaround that is too ugly for me to stomach:  duplicate the above CSS styling for each cell in the table.  My table has 48 elements...)

Comment: assign classes or use attribute and/or nth selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the class into the dynamically created input:

```
row.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = i&&j ? "<input id='"+ letter+i +"' style='myInputClass' />" : i||letter
```

And change your CSS classes to use `myInputClass` instead of `input`

Comment: Thank you!  I guessed at that solution, but mistakenly thought I had to double quote the class name ('"myInputClass"'), which gave me an error.

Comment: We've all been there! Reminder: Please mark this response as the answer if it fit your criteria for such.